# Make footer height extend to bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very simple webpage with a problem. It ahs 3 divs that sit ontop of each other, the header, content then footer.

**I want my footers height to expand to the bottom of the page. How can I do this?**

The header has a constant height, the content will vary in height depending on the content received from an AJAX call. So I cant explicitly set it.

Heres my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5U6ZB/2/embedded/result/

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="content">
    <!-- height is dynamic sometimes it will be full of divs that makes it
         longer than the screen height other times it only has 1 div  -->
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <!-- How do I make the footer height fill up the rest of the page height? -->
</div>

body { background-color: white; }
div  { width: 100%; }

#header {
    height: 400px;
    background-color: RGB(200,200,200);
}

#content {

}

#footer {
    background-color: RGB(112,112,112);
    /*How do I make the footer height fill up the rest of the page height?*/
}
```

Answer (score 20):

```
html {
background-color:#093; /*the footer color*/
}

body {

background-color: #f6f; /*the body color*/
}
```

Comment: Not quite what was asked, but I imagine exactly what he was after - certainly, it was exactly what I was after when I ended up on this page! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the easiest solution in your case would be to make the body background the same colour as the footer and make your content white. This would give the illusion of the footer going all the way to the bottom.

```
body { background-color:RGB(112,112,112); }
div  { width: 100%; } /* Divs are block elements which automatically take 100% width so this is redundant. */

#header {
    height: 400px;
    background-color: RGB(200,200,200);
}

#content {
    background-color:white;
}

#footer {
    background-color: RGB(112,112,112);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
:root {
    background-color: siteBackgroundColor;
}

body {
    background-color: footerColor;
}
```

This doesn't really expand the footer, but visually expands its background color.

Comment: It's the opposite of this, isn't it? Set `:root`'s background to match the footer and `body`'s to match the site.

Answer (score 2):

A similar approach to fayerth's, this will adjust height dynamically when the browser is resized (and is based on jQuery).

Instead of resizing the footer directly, I added the additional empty element `<div class="flex-footer">` and resized that instead. My thought is that it should give a less jittery effect if the footer contains a bunch of elements as well as not fussing with any children of the footer that are sized relative to the parent.

Your CSS should then apply whatever background color necessary.

Note my comment about negative margins. This was necessary in my case since the design required the use of negative margins. I've included that bit in case yours does as well.

```
    $(function(){
        $(window).load(resizeFooter);
        $(window).resize(resizeFooter);
    });
    // Dynamically resize footer to fill page, IE8 doesn't like this.
    function resizeFooter() {
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var headerHeight = $("header").height();
        var contentHeight = $("div.main").height();
        var footerHeight = $("footer").height();
        // 107 references a negative margin in header - you'll need to account for this if necessary
        var flexFooter = windowHeight - (headerHeight + contentHeight + footerHeight - 107);
        $(".flex-footer").css("min-height", flexFooter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In pure CSS, it's not possible, but if you want to use some fancy Javascript, you can dynamically change the height of the footer to stretch the remaining height, assuming the content doesn't already do it for you.

```
var header = document.getElementById("header"),
    content = document.getElementById("content"),
    footer = document.getElementById("footer"),
    height = window.screen.height - header.clientHeight - content.clientHeight;

footer.clientHeight = (height < 150) ? 150 : height; // Sets a minimum height of 150px
```

It's usually better to follow SynXsiS's suggestion though, as it tends to give a nicer appearance. In the end, it really depends on the way you design the look and feel of your page.

Answer (score 1):

very simple, and works for me :)

> footer{ position:absolute; width:100%; top: (read below);   }

you can try with diferent percents values in top property, when the footer take the desired place in your screen, that percent will apply to all resolutions :)

Comment: nice, without javascript, i still have to test it against some browsers

Answer (score 0):

I am tweaking a wordpress theme - and have the same problem. But - if I implement a sticky footer, it actually partially scrolls away with the content. Wordpress is a mess so I'm not sure why it's doing this - but what I need is to let the footer sit below the main content, but THEN fill the rest of the screen so it doesn't look silly on shorter pages.

Any ideas of an easy CSS fix other than the color trick? (which I may do ;)

Claudia