# Footer which takes the rest of the remaining window height but at least a specified amount of px

Tags: html, css, height

I found several questions about but none of their solutions was working for me so here we go again.

Let's say I have this template of HTML

```
<html>
  <div id="header">...</div>
  <div id="contentA">...</div>
  <div id="contentB">...</div>
  <div id="footer">...</div>
</html>
```

The footer div should be at least 80px height, but if those 80px plus the height of all other 3 divs is not enough to fullfill the screen I want the footer to increase as much as the screen is filled with it below header, contentA and contentB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BG-Color Solution**

If you just want to let the remaining space have the same background-color as the footer (but not the body), you could add the footer bg-color to the html-tag:

```
html {
    background-color: #footer_color;
}

body {
    background-color: #body_color;
}

#footer {
    min-height: 80px;
}
```

.

**JS-Solution**

If you have something more complex within your footer, you could use javascript/jquery to calculate the remaining space and set the footer to that height.

There is a similar question with a code example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14329340/3589841

.

**Flexbox-Solution**

If you only care about the latest browsers you can use the flexbox-box-model:

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="flex_container">
        <div id="header">...</div>
        <div id="contentA">...</div>
        <div id="contentB">...</div>
        <div id="footer">...</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

#flex_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

#header {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#contentA {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#contentB {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#footer {
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    min-height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Since I don't like to use JS for something like this and add some extra rules for customer who won't use JS for security reason - thats a no go for me. The flex solution looks great - looking forward to use it in near future. As long as stay with the Background solution which is a simple quick and dirty useful solution. Thank you a lot for sharing :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Could you mark it as the right answer please? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're going for something like this, have a look http://jsfiddle.net/dusUK/

Using CSS, we create a class, which in this case is fullheight, and we apply the following:

```
.fullheight {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
}
```

We also then apply the following to html, body

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No, thats not working. It will always expand the footer more as wanted :/